# SwiftUI Label with dynamic image

Tags: image, swiftui, label

It is possible to use a dynamic image within a Label ?

Something like :

```
Label("SP98", uiImage: myFunctionToReturnImageFromText("test"))
```

used in this context :

```
Menu {
                            
                            if fuelTypeisAvailable(fuelType: "Diesel") {
                                
                                Button {
                                    updateStuff()
                                    Haptics.shared.play(.light)
                                    preferredFuelType = "Diesel"
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Diesel", systemImage: "fuelpump.circle")
                                   
                  

          }
                        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just using: `Label("title", image: "image")`?

Comment: I want the image to be dynamic. So I don't have the text string name. I want to supply a uiImage.

Comment: The simple answer is yes. You haven't posted a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but `Label` does not accept a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the initializer that you want to use is:

```
Label {
   Text("SP98")
} icon: {
   Image(uiImage: myFunctionToReturnImageFromText("test"))

}
```

Comment: I think Is close but it doesn't play nice within a Menu apparently. Sorry didn't specify that.

Comment: Well, you got the answer to the question asked. You should accept it and ask a better question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```swift
struct ImageLabel: View {
    
    let title: String
    let image: Image
    
    public init(_ title: String, uiImage: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
    
    public init(_ title: String, image: Image) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
        image
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple recommends that you never use `AnyView`. Also, this returns two separate `Views` simultaneously.

Comment: @Yrb returns two separate Views but if you put it in a hstack or vstack, it will work well

Comment: OP wants a `Label`